# Bootstrap 3 - element won't stay in the width of the div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 in a small div. When I increase the window's width by dragging the window - the fields (username and password input fields) that are supposed to stay in the interior of the div move out to almost the center of the window. Why? CSS and HTML are below

```
<body>
  <div class="login">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
          <form action="https://www.blah/login"/>
          <h3>Login</h3>
            <div class="col-xs-4">UserName:</div>
              <div class="col-xs-8"><input class="rounded white" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username:" required/><br></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">Password:</div>
              <div class="col-xs-8"><input class="rounded white" type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password:" required/><br></div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="retrieve" value="true"/>I forgot my password.
          <ul class="no-bullets">
            <li><input class="color-brown white rounded float-left" type="submit" name="register" value="Submit Now"></li>
            <li><input class="rounded margin-left-5px" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" value="Cancel"></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS----

```
.login {
  height: 200px;
  width: 330px;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #242424;
  border: 1px solid #545454;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09f7sv9q/)

Comment: Here's the fiddle you just posted, revised with one additional line of code: https://jsfiddle.net/09f7sv9q/1/ ... For more details see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements containing your labels (`.col-xs-4`) have a `width: 33.33333%`.

The elements containing your input fields (`.col-xs-8`) have a `width: 66.6666667%`.

When the screen is narrow these width values are small and the labels and inputs are close together.

When the screen expands, these width values expand as well, creating a progressively larger gap between label and input.

**The answer is to give the container a width constraint.**

Add this style to the container class:

```
.col-md-12 { max-width: 250px; }
```

I tested it in Chrome and it works. Also, here's a live demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/y0psw5dn/

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to inproperly set `.login` to `height:200px`.

```
    .login{
         /*height:200px*/
    }
```

[Is is what you want?](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpPNWo)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="login">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="https://www.blah/login" />
         <h3>Login</h3>

        <div class="col-xs-4">UserName:</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input class="rounded white" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username:" required/>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">Password:</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input class="rounded white" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password:" required/>
            <br>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="retrieve" value="true" />I forgot my password.
        <ul class="no-bullets">
            <li>
                <input class="color-brown white rounded float-left" type="submit" name="register" value="Submit Now">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input class="rounded margin-left-5px" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" value="Cancel">
            </li>
        </ul>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>

.login {
    height: 200px;
    width: 330px;
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color: #242424;
    border: 1px solid #545454;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ddd;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/09f7sv9q/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `.login` div under the `.container` div. Below the code is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="login">
```

See the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/09f7sv9q/4/) demo.

I changed your structure. There was some wrong. You can check this demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/09f7sv9q/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your upper starting structure of your html like this only

```html
 <div class="container">
         <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="login">
```

> the problem is with your html structure still many wrong things are
>   present you can make it better just try to improve by understanding the **grid system of Bootstrap**

it happens because of the improper structure sequence so that

here is the working demo jsfiddle

[DEMO check out](https://jsfiddle.net/09f7sv9q/8/)

---

**here i tried to modify your code my way you can check out**

```css
.login {
  height:280px;
    max-width:250px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #242424;
  border: 1px solid #545454;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ddd;
}
.temp_div{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.forgetPass_check{
    padding-right:5px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.forgetPass_label{
    padding-left:10px;
}
.no-bullets{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
ul.no-bullets li{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
         <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="login">                 
                  <form action="https://www.blah/login"/>
                  <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>                 
                 <div class="col-xs-8"><label>UserName:</label><input class="rounded white" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username:" required/></div>
                 <div class="col-xs-8"><label>Password:</label><input class="rounded white" type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password:" required/></div>
                 <div class="temp_div"> 
                      <div class="forgetPass_check">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="retrieve" value="true"/><label class="forgetPass_label">I forgot my password.</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="button_wrapper">
                          <ul class="no-bullets">
                            <li><input class="color-brown white rounded float-left" type="submit" name="register" value="Submit Now"></li>
                            <li><input class="rounded margin-left-5px" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" value="Cancel"></li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                  </div>                 
             </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

here is the demo code as well

[Please Check Out Modified](https://jsfiddle.net/09f7sv9q/11/)

even you can check this

[Another try](https://jsfiddle.net/09f7sv9q/13/)

Comment: @MichaelDWheeler check out the answer dude

Answer (score 0):

I also using Bootstrap 3 here Just Check it out this code.
Your HTML code structure is not organized here. First you need to understand its row and columns architecture what the purpose Behind it.

and Here on many places you open the div but you are not closing your at proper Location Where you need to close it.

I used this HTML Code :

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="col-md-12 login">         
      <form action="https://www.blah/login"/>
      <h3>Login</h3>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">UserName:</div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input class="rounded white" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/><br>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">Password:</div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input class="rounded white" type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" required/><br>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="checkbox" name="retrieve" value="true"/> I forgot my password.
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6">
               <input class="bg-default btn-font" type="submit" name="register" value="Submit Now">
              </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
               <input class="bg-default btn-font" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" value="Cancel">
              </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

and css code is here:

```
.login {  height: 200px; width: 330px;  max-width: 330px;  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;  background-color: #242424;  border: 1px solid #545454;  border-radius: 10px;  color: #ddd; }  .btn-font{   color: #000; }
```

and here is my running fiddle Example:

[For Demo Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yash_mangla/xzc8qpy5/)

Answer (score 0):

hi  please check below code it should be within container...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="login">
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
      <form action="https://www.blah/login"/>
      <h3>Login</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-4">UserName:</div>
          <div class="col-xs-8"><input class="rounded white" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username:" required/><br></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">Password:</div>
          <div class="col-xs-8"><input class="rounded white" type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password:" required/><br></div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="retrieve" value="true"/>I forgot my password.
      <ul class="no-bullets">
        <li><input class="color-brown white rounded float-left" type="submit" name="register" value="Submit Now"></li>
        <li><input class="rounded margin-left-5px" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" value="Cancel"></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

check the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharD/09f7sv9q/10/) here